# Spring Websockets with JWT

Tags: angular, spring, websocket, jwt, stomp

I am implementing websocket communication between Spring and Angular using `Stomp`. I am not using session based authentication, but `JWT` authentication. I encounter a problem with `SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser()` method. Since I have no session based authentication, Spring doesn't know how to find a way to connect `simpSessionId` with destination user login. I have tried this one https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/src/docs/asciidoc/web/websocket.adoc#token-authentication adding `Authorization` header, but i can't since it is `Http` header, not `websocket`. How can i prepare my backend and frontend application, to enable `convertAndSendToUser()` mechanism? How do i pass `Authorization` header while websocket connection is beeing established? I have checked couple of topics on `Stackoverflow` but noone of them are actually a sollution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a queryparamter and add it to your socket url. Then you need to addapt your JwtAuthorizationFilter, to look for the querparamter if the header is empty. This is working perfectly for a internal application, **but I don't know the risks adding the JWT to the url, you should consider this!**

```
    /**
     * Parses received jwt.
     *
     * @param req Http request from user.
     * @return Authentication token for the user.
     */
    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String token = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token == null) {
            String[] params = request.getParameterValues("token");
            if(params.length == 1){
                token = TOKEN_TYPE + params[0];
            }
        }


        if (token != null) {
            try {
                // [...]
                }
            } catch (JwtException e) {
                // In case token is expired or invalid. Prevents status 500.
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

On the angular side I used:

```
Stomp.client(`${this.url}?token=${this.jwt}`);
```